# How to continue CSS animation on :hover after mouse leave the element?

Tags: html, css, animation

There is example of animation:

```
.b-ball_bounce {transform-origin: top;}
@-webkit-keyframes ball_animation {
    20%   {transform: rotate(-9deg);}
    40%  {transform: rotate(6deg);}
    60%  {transform: rotate(-3deg);}
    80% {transform: rotate(1.5deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
}
.b-ball_bounce:hover {
  -webkit-animation: ball_animation 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

When mouse hover an element animation start. But when mouse leave, animation stops immediately. But I want to finish animation after mouse leave.

This is example with help of JavaScript: http://codepen.io/Profesor08/pen/pvbzjX
And I want to do the same with pure CSS3, there is how it looks now: http://codepen.io/Profesor08/pen/WbxeoW

Comment: Nope! It's not possible with pure CSS.

Comment: Another point: Looks like you're using jquery in your first example (not 'javascript').

Comment: @jbutler483, how is jQuery not JavaScript? :)

Comment: I was trying to say *jQuery is a set of JavaScript libraries*; and so it would help people find this Question who would be more 'familiar' with jquery (as you rightly mentioned there 'are the same', but ultimately, 'novice' web devs. do not realise there is a difference whatsoever). Much like **javascript** and **typescript**

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot of stuff with transition:

```css
#some-div {
    background-color: rgba(100,100,0,0.2);
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
#some-div:hover { background-color: rgba(100,0,0,0.7); }
```

Look at the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opyb6u9b/) or look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) for more

Comment: And where is the answer? You made the same, but with transitions. But anyway, animation stops on mouse leave the eliment.

Answer (score 0):

CSS might help in some cases but not all, below is the code that will animate letter spacing on both hover and after hover.

```css
h1
{
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
}

h1:hover
{
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
    letter-spacing:3px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this we can use javascript to append the CSS class "onMouseEnter" and remove the class "onAnimationEnd" and completly remove the :hover tag from our css.

React example:

```js
        onMouseEnter={(e) => e.currentTarget.classList.add('bounce') } 
        onAnimationEnd={(e) => e.currentTarget.classList.remove('bounce')}
```

Working Example: https://codepen.io/jamesprenticez/pen/jOpQvPP

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use pseudo :hover element

here you have to apply transition of the div or element you want to use.

transition: width 1s ease;

Also, you can use set timeout function using JavaScript if you want it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).