# How to do a full transition when hovered over an element?

Tags: html, css

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.box:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

If the cursor is over the .box for less than a second, the transition stops and falls back to it's original phase.
Is there a way to somehow force the whole animation, regardless of hover duration?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2bce9ufr/)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7694323/3597276

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27504301/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: Similar solution but relying on transition and animation: https://jsfiddle.net/ok7pnrsL/

---

This is my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/9yu0cozq/1/

Basically you need to add a container for the box and then play with CSS  animations.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

When the mouse enters the .box then the hidden container appears (please note that for this to work that container should have enough width and height to fit the whole area where the mouse might go).
This container creates an animation for itself to "hide" back in 1s. and while it is shown the .box has an animation for the same time.

```
#container {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
#container:hover{
    animation-name:changeSize;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
#container:hover .box{
    animation-name:changeColor;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
.box {
    z-index:0;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    transition:1s background;
}
.box:hover {
    background: yellow;
}
@keyframes changeColor {
    0% {
    background: red;
    }
    100% {
    background: yellow;
    }
}
@keyframes changeSize {
    0%,99% {
    width: 100%;height: 100%;
    }
    100% {
    width: 0;height: 0;
    }
}
```

So, without knowing the real context, this solution gives a series of assumptions that might or might not fit your exact case but gives an idea of how to solve it using pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you heave to use JS for this. First you need to create animation for background change, and and then you can set it as class and add that class on hover, and remove it when animation ends or on `webkitAnimationEnd`.

```js
$('.box').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('animate');
  $(this).on('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('animate');
  })
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
.box.animate {
  animation: changeColor 2s linear;
}
@keyframes changeColor {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  50% {
    background: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I'm interested in a pure css way, but thank you for the answer!

Comment: This is very close, you just `add/remove` class with js and the rest is pure css, but i would also like to see if this can be done with just css.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this without javascript, but it would be interesting to find out.

A light weight javascript solution could be something like this:

```
// Get the elemnt
var myDiv = document.getElementById('box');

// Detect hover
myDiv.onmouseover = function() { 
  // Add a force class to the element
  myDiv.className += " force";
  // Reset the cass name after 1sec (100ms)
  setTimeout(function(){ myDiv.className = "box"; }, 1000, myDiv);
}
```

Change your markup slightly to make things easier for now:

```
<div id="box" class="box"></div>
```

And add an extra class to your css styles along with the hover state:

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.box.force,
.box:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davey182673/k021013u/1/)