# Pseudo element (::before) is hover out animation keep going

Tags: css, hover, css-animations

I nee help on something very specific (i guess)

I have "li" block with ::before pseudo element
`<li id="phone">XX XX XX XX XX</li>`

```
li::before
  display: block                        
  content: ""
  width: 17px
  height: 17px
  margin-right: 8px
  position: relative
  align-items: center
  background: blue
```

So i animate the pseudo block when the "li" is hover like so :

```
li:hover::before
  animation-name: hover-wriggle
  animation-duration: 2s
  animation-fill-mode: forwards
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse
  animation-iteration-count: infinite
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out
```

```
@keyframes hover-wriggle
  0%
    transform: rotate(50deg)
  50%
    transform: rotate(-50deg)
  100%
    transform: rotate(0deg)
```

When i hover the "li" he move, when i quit i want them to keep doing animation for like 1sec ? This is possible (without JS !) ?

Thanks ! Happy Coding <3

Comment: Transition will help, as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504301/how-to-continue-css-animation-on-hover-after-mouse-leave-the-element), **but** only when there is **1 animation effect**,you have two(right and left turn) ,so i think impossible without js

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i still learning the « transition » and you help a lot !